# Reading Nested data from ElasticSearch via Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am trying to read data from Elasticsearch via Spark Scala:

Scala 2.11.8, Spark 2.3.0, Elasticsearch 5.6.8

To Connect -- `spark2-shell --jars elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.6.8.jar`

```
val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.nodes", "xxxxxxx").option("es.port", "xxxx").option("es.net.http.auth.user","xxxxx").option("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "xxxxxx").option("es.net.ssl", "true").option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true").option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true").option("es.net.ssl.truststore.location", "xxxxx").option("es.net.ssl.truststore.pass", "xxxxx").option("es.read.field.as.array.include","true").option("pushdown", "true").option("es.read.field.as.array.include","a4,a4.a41,a4.a42,a4.a43,a4.a43.a431,a4.a43.a432,a4.a44,a4.a45").load("<index_name>")
```

Schema as below

```
 |-- a1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a31: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a32: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- a4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a41: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a42: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a43: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a431: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a432: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a44: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a45: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a9: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a91: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a92: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a10: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a11: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Though I am able to read data from direct columns and nested schema level 1 (i.e a9 or a3 columns) via command:

```
df.select(explode($"a9").as("exploded")).select("exploded.*").show
```

Problem is occuring when I am trying to read a4 elements as its throwing me below error:

```
    [Stage 18:>                                                         (0 + 1) / 1]20/02/28 02:43:23 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 54, xxxxxxx, executor 12): scala.MatchError: Buffer() (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter$$anonfun$toCatalystImpl$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:164)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:379)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:57)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:211)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:381)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20/02/28 02:43:23 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 57, xxxxxxx, executor 12): scala.MatchError: Buffer() (of class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:231)
```

Anything I am doing wrong or any steps I am missing? Please Help

Comment: error that you have printed is not actual error i think, could you please share log from start.

Comment: @Nikk: That what error said.. though I have added full error also.. Info wise there is not much in the error.....

Comment: @Appy22 No luck yet. Still looking into this

Comment: @Opster ES Ninja - Kamal Okay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the top of my head, this error occurs when the schema guessed by the spark/ElasticSearch connector is not actually compatible with the data being read.

Keep in my that *ES is schemaless*, and *SparkSQL has a "hard" schema*. Bridging this gap is not always possible, so it's all just a best effort.

When connecting the two, the connector samples the documents and tries to guess a schema : "field A is a string, field B is an object structure with two subfield : B.1 being a date, and B.2 being an array of strings, ... whatever".

If it guessed wrong (typically : a given column / subcolumn is guessed as being a String, but in some documents it in fact is an array or a number), then the JSON to SparkSQL conversion emits those kind of errors.

In the words of the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/mapping.html#mapping-multi-values), it states :

> Elasticsearch treats fields with single or multi-values the same; in fact, the mapping provides no information about this. As a client, it means one cannot tell whether a field is single-valued or not until is actually being read. In most cases this is not an issue and elasticsearch-hadoop automatically creates the necessary list/array on the fly. However in environments with strict schema such as Spark SQL, changing a field actual value from its declared type is not allowed. Worse yet, this information needs to be available even before reading the data. Since the mapping is not conclusive enough, elasticsearch-hadoop allows the user to specify the extra information through field information, specifically es.read.field.as.array.include and es.read.field.as.array.exclude.

So I'd adivse you to check that the schema you reported in your question (the schema guessed by Spark) is actually valid agains all your documents, or not.

If it's not, you have a few options going forward :

1. Correct the mapping individually. If the problem is linked to an array type not being recognized as such, you can do so using [configuration options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html). You can see the `es.read.field.as.array.include` (resp. `.exclude`) option (which is used to actively tell Spark which properties in the documents are array (resp. not array). If a field is unused, `es.read.field.exclude` is an option that will exclude a given field from Spark altogether, bypassing possible schema issus for it.
2. If there is no way to provide a valid schema for all cases to ElasticSearch (e.g. some field is sometimes a number, somtimes a string, and there is no way to tell), then basically, you're stuck to going back at the RDD level (and if need be, go back to Dataset / Dataframe once the schema is well defined).